# Filter data with !is.na() . Alternative to !is na?

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate a code so this is my following code:

```
statefips <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kjhealy/fips-codes/master/state_fips_master.csv")  %>%
  select(state_name, state_abbr, region_name, division_name) %>% dplyr::rename(state = state_name)
```

That code works fine.

But there is an issue here:

```
uspop <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JoseMontoya518/uspop2018/master/PEP_2018_PEPSR6H_with_ann.csv") %>%
  janitor::clean_names()%>%
  dplyr::filter(year_id == "est72018", !is.na(statefips))
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..2`.
x Input `..2` must be of size 5149 or 1, not size 50.
i Input `..2` is `!is.na(statefips)`.
```

So I try another way , instead of adding:

```
!is.na(statefips)
```

as an input in filter function. I use this:

```
%>% na.exclude
```

So this is the final code:

```
   uspop <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JoseMontoya518/uspop2018/master/PEP_2018_PEPSR6H_with_ann.csv") %>%
      janitor::clean_names()%>%
      dplyr::filter(year_id == "est72018")%>% na.exclude
```

That code works ,but I don't know if the purpose of the code is achieved.

```
!is.na(statefips)
```

was added as an input for a reason in the code which I'm replicating. When I remove %>% na.exclude, nothing change from the original data frame:

```
 uspop <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JoseMontoya518/uspop2018/master/PEP_2018_PEPSR6H_with_ann.csv") %>%
          janitor::clean_names()%>%
          dplyr::filter(year_id == "est72018")
```

So , Is there a way to filter the data with this input: !is.na(statefips) ?

Comment: With your code you are filtering the data you want to store in object `uspop`. The first condition, `year_id == "est72018"`, works because you have indeed a column with such a name in the csv file you are importing. That being said you have no variable named *statefips* in `uspop` so the function throws an error. When you change your code, nothing changes because `uspop` does not contain any observation whose value is NA (no missing observations therefore)

Comment: @davidnortes So there is no reason to filter with !is.na input right?

Comment: You can do it if you want to or if you think is a good practice but in this particular case you do not seem to need it